# What is the best way to render a search bar component that takes in a props in another component using react v6

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, search, react-router

I have my search component that is supposed to be passed into a header component but the tutorial I am using is old and was using an older version of react.

This is my Search.js component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Search = ({ history }) => {

    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

    const searchHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if (keyword.trim()) {
            history.push(`/search/${keyword}`)
        } else {
            history.push('/')
        }
    }

    console.log('my keyword', keyword);

    return (
            <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
                 <div className="input-group">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="search_field"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Product Name ..."
                        onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <div className="input-group-append">
                        <button id="search_btn" className="btn">
                        <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
        </div>
            </form>       
    )
}

export default Search
```

And this is how I pass it into my Header.js component

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'
import { logout } from '../../actions/userActions'

import Search from './Search'

import '../../App.css'

const Header = () => {
    
    
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <nav className="navbar row">
                <div className="col-12 col-md-6 mt-2 mt-md-0">
                
                    <Route render={({ history }) => <Search history={history} />} />
                    
                </div>
             </nav>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Whenever I run the code it tells me I need to wrap it in a `<Routes>`

I did it like this

```
<Routes> 
  <Route render={({ history }) => <Search history={history} />} />
</Routes>
```

But when I wrap it like this it doesn't give any errors but the search bar doesn't show at all in my browser header

What is the correct way to render this please?

I also read that the `history.push` in my search.js has been replaced by a `useNavigate` so I tried changing that to make my Search.js look like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Search = ({  }) => {
   
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const searchHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if (keyword.trim()) {
            navigate(`/search/${keyword}`)
        } else {
            navigate('/search')
        }
    }

    console.log('my keyword', keyword);

    return (
            <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
                 <div className="input-group">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="search_field"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Product Name ..."
                        onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <div className="input-group-append">
                        <button id="search_btn" className="btn">
                        <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
        </div>
            </form>       
    )
}

export default Search
```

But I have no idea how to render it properly in my `Header` component

Comment: You need to set the path on, `<Route path="/some-path" />`. The router doesn't know to render it. You also don't need to use a render prop to pass history to `<Search />`. Just use the `useHistory` hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell you are using `react-router-dom` v6, so your last snippet  of the `Search` component using the `useNavigate` hook is correct.

```
const Search = () => {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const searchHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (keyword.trim()) {
      navigate(`/search/${keyword}`);
    } else {
      navigate("/search");
    }
  };

  console.log("my keyword", keyword);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
      <div className="input-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="search_field"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Product Name ..."
          onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button id="search_btn" className="btn">
            <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

But the issue is that you are trying to render it on a `Route` using the older RRDv5 `Route` APIs.

```
<Route render={({ history }) => <Search history={history} />} />
```

In v6 gone are the `component`, and `render` and `children` function props. Gone also are the route props, i.e. `history`, `location`, and `match`, this is why you need the `useNavigate` hook to get the `navigate` function in `Search`.

From what I can tell, `Search` was only rendered by a `Route` in the old tutorial simply to have the `history` object passed in as a prop. I don't see any reason for it to be rendered by a `Route`. Just render `Search` directly in the `Header`.

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar row">
      <div className="col-12 col-md-6 mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <Search />
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Assuming the `Header` component is rendered within a routing context provided by a router (*`BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`, `MemoryRouter`, etc...*) the `useNavigate` hook will work.

Comment: Thanks it finally shows in my header. My App.js uses the BrowserRouter. I did it like you said, and my console.log in my search component shows any keyword I type in the search bar  but when I click search it goes to the /search/$keyword as it should but no data is returned, when I test the route in post man it works but in the Browser it doesn't. Why isn't it please?

Comment: @JoeySmith What data are you expecting to be returned when you navigate to `\`/search/${keyword}\``, and what/where are you expecting it to be returned to? Is the component on *that* route path supposed to fetch some data? This seems extra-curricular to your posted question here.

Comment: with your help my search bar was actually working. but i had a problem on my backend that i didnt realise early. i just fixed my productController for the get all products and its working properly. asking me where it was fetching data made me go over my backend line by line. Again Thank You so much

Comment: @JoeySmith Great! Glad to hear it sounds like you got that lingering issue sorted out. Cheers.